# Using abstract with Binary Search in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a task in kotlin to use an abstract class, and the example was about binary search 
so it shows an error message in the run.
first class is non

- first class there's a non abstract class but it a parent class
- second an abstract class the inherite the parent classes
- third a class that display the operation

and that's my code:

```
open class BinarySearch() {
    fun BinarySearchFunction(arr: Array<Int>, l: Int, r: Int, x: Int): Int {
        if(r >= 1) {
          var mid:Int=1+(r-1)/2
            if (arr[mid] == x) {
              return mid
            }
          if(arr[mid] > x){
            return BinarySearchFunction(arr,l,mid-1,x)
          }
          return BinarySearchFunction(arr,mid+1,r,x)
        }
      return -1
    }
      
    open fun displayMassage(Massage:String){}

}

abstract class print(): BinarySearch() {
  fun Function() {
     var obj = BinarySearch()
     var a = arrayOf<Int>(2, 3, 4, 10, 40)
     var n = a.size
     var x = 10
     var result = obj.BinarySearchFunction(a, 0, n - 1, x)
     if(result == -1)
         println("Element not present")
     else
         println("Element found at index $result")
  }
}

 class display():print(){
      override fun displayMassage(massage:String){
          println(massage)
     }
 }

fun main() {
    var dis=display()
    dis.displayMassage("The Binary Search : ")
    dis.Function()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the implementation of the algorithm causing it to do infinite recursion.

I believe

```
var mid: Int = 1 + (r - 1) / 2
```

actually needs to be

```
var mid: Int = l + (r - 1) / 2
```